# Java Reflection in multimodule maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven

Project 1 : pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>project2</groupId>
            <artifactId>project2</artifactId>
            <version>{someversion}</version>
        </dependency>
```

project 2: another maven spring project

project 1 and project 2 both are spring maven projects.From above architecture project 2 has been added as a library to project 1. My question is can I invoke **project 1 class from project 2**  using reflection?

Answer (score 0):

In general yes, you can access of project2 from project1 at runtime. **It will work both by "regular" class invocation and by reflection**.

Otherwise why did you add the dependency? ;)

One caveat though:
You state that both projects are "maven spring projects". You haven't explicitly stated the spring boot, but if project2 is a spring boot project and the jar is created with the help of `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, its impossible to make such a dependency because `project2.jar` is not really a jar (although it has the .jar extension).

Comment: My question is not accessing project 2 in project 1, that definitely we can. But My question is can I invoke project 1 classes in project 2 using reflection.

Comment: Yes, as I said - it doesn't matter whether you would like to work with reflection or with direct invocation. Both will work. Maven is a build tool, so when you build the module, the fact that project1 has a dependency on project2 means that in project1' classes you can access project2's classes either by reflection or by "regular" invocation/reference.

Comment: my question is reversed, in project2' classes can you access project1's classes

Comment: No, it won't event compile during the build. Now if you're working by reflection and do not specify any class names (only strings and classes from `java.lang.reflect` package) it will compile. Since maven is a build tool the whole mechanism of dependencies matters in build time. In runtime you'll be able to access any class from any place as long as its in the classpath. However note, what you describe, might point on some design issue.

Comment: I am using a event triggering in a separate library annotation based. In project 1 I am using annotation and implementation in project2 that is of generic type. At run time It will decide which class methods to invoke to read and operate on data.

Comment: Well, I think my answer is applicable in this case as well... :)

Comment: @Techie321 I am pretty sure that your problem has much nicer solution than trying to call a non-dependency by reflection.

Answer (score -1):

**Adding the Library Dependency**

The Application project needs to have a dependency on the Library project. You need to modify your Application build file accordingly.[More Details](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/)

For Maven, add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>library</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>COPY
```

The following listing shows the finished pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>multi-module-application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>multi-module-application</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```